# Is there a macro that checks if a given function exists

Tags: c++, c, function, macros

My application is using a library, and there are many versions of this library. I'm calling a function from this library. The name of the function is `function_name` (just an example) in one version of the library, but in other versions the same function has another name, `another_function_name`.

Is there a macro that checks if a given function exists?

Usage example:

```
#ifexist function_name
#define MYFUNCTION function_name
#else
#define MYFUNCTION another_function_name
#endif
```

Comment: Macros are expanded before functions are dealt with. What's the real issue?

Comment: Existence of functions is compile-time. Try taking a function's address, and your linker will slap you in the face if it doesn't exist. ;-)

Comment: This smells like an XY-problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: @chris My application is using library. and there is many version of this libray. I m calling a function from this libray. the name of the function is `toto` and in other versions the same function has another name `titi`

Comment: sounds like a pre-build task. you can use some standard tool like `autoconf/automake` to figure out the environment.

Comment: @MOHAMED: Then you should check the version of the library, not the existence of a function. Most libraries have a `VERSION` compile-time constant in a central header (`version.h`?) you can check. @KarolyHorvath: Nice jump from C source to build system. What if he's using CMake, or MSVC? ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar but this libray does not. so that's why I m looking for an alternative. the library is libubox

Comment: if a function doesn't exist, your compiler will let you know... and you won't be able to compile your code. Unless, of course, you're actually using C++, not C, and are overloading all functions 200+ times :P

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can also dynamically load your function via [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)/[GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx). If one function doesn't exist, call the other one.

Comment: Check the header file of the library that you are using. It should contain some preprocessor definition which can be used in order to uniquely identify the version of the library. Use this definition in order to decide whether to call `toto` or `titi`.

Comment: @MOHAMED: And this is the point where you should close this question, and open another one asking "how to distinguish between libubox version X with `functionA()` and version Y with `functionB()`" (filling in the functions you are referring to). Because yes, this *is* a XY-problem, ref. alk's comment. Also, think about sending in a feature request to the lib's maintainer, because it's a shortcoming of libubox if it's really the case.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a macro that checks if a given function exists?

No. You are looking at the wrong end of the process of translating your c++ source files into an executable. Macro processing occurs very early on in the process. Resolving external references and building the executable is the very last step. The preprocessor doesn't know about libraries. It doesn't even know about functions.

At a minimum that library should be associated with some header files that you `#include` in your source code. You yourself should not have to declare the classes and functions that that library provides. A well-build library will also define preprocessor symbols that specify the version of the library. For example, The header `some_library.h` may define the symbols `SOME_LIBRARY_MAJOR_VERSION` and `SOME_LIBRARY_MINOR_VERSION`.

It is these preprocessor symbols that you should use to determine what function you should call. Suppose you know that you should be calling `function_name` with version 1.3 of the library and earlier, but `another_function_name` with version 1.4 and later. You can make a preprocessor symbol `MYFUNCTION` that is defined based on the library's version ID macros:

```
#if (SOME_LIBRARY_MAJOR_VERSION == 1) && (SOME_LIBRARY_MINOR_VERSION <= 3)
#define MYFUNCTION function_name
#else
#define MYFUNCTION another_function_name
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the behaviour you're looking for is to have multiple implementations of the same function. Unless there is an implementation given on another spot in the code, the linker will use default implementation given by the weak symbol

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol